# Trouble with warehouse directory in HIVE

Tags: ubuntu, hive, hadoop2

Following [the article to install HIVE](http://www.edureka.co/blog/apache-hive-installation-on-ubuntu/), I came across the instruction to create a directory called `warehouse`, using the command `hadoop fs -mkdir -p /usr/lib/hive/warehouse` (i changed the path to suit my installation). Now, as such I haven't had any issues working with HIVE **yet** (and I haven't advanced a lot so I can't be sure), but when I go to that path (`/usr/lib/hive/warehouse`) I do not see a directory by that name. I tried creating dummy directories too, with that command, but I don't see anything there.

Am I doing something wrong? Should I actually see something there? I have gone thought the article a couple of times, but nothing seems to strike me.

It's an Ubuntu 15.10 machine and Hadoop Gen2.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Show databases and show tables are hive commands to list databases or tables. To see files for the tables you can use hadoop fs command in Linux terminal or dfs command in hive.

Answer (score 0):

Typically the path should be /user/hive/warehouse.

If you are using custom location, you have to follow these steps:

1. hadoop fs -mkdir -P /usr/lib/hive/warehouse
2. hadoop fs -chmod -R 777 /usr/lib/hive/warehouse
3. Restart the hive components

Comment: Did all that, but still it says `bash: cd: warehouse: No such file or directory`

Comment: Does the directory made on `hadoop fs` show up? `ls -a` isn't showing anything either.

Comment: When I run `hduser@mymachine:/usr/lib/hive$ cd warehouse`. There's just no directory by that name! I tried `sudo mkdir test` at /usr/lib/hive and it created a directory with no problem. I wonder what's going on.

Comment: is `hadoop fs -mkdir -P /usr/lib/hive/warehouse` supposed to create a visible directory at all? At this point, because HIVE itself is working, I do not mind this. But I know that the tables and the dbs are stored in that directory, so wanted to know

Comment: Yes it will not be. Directories and files in HDFS are visible only under hadoop fs commands. You cannot find those in Linux file system. You need to understand difference between HDFS and local Linux file system and their commands.

Comment: I see! Ok, so in case I create a db or a table, there's no way to see them on my machine locally? I need to rely on `show databases` and `show tables`, what `hadoop` shows me. Correct?

Comment: You don't say if you're running in pseudo-distributed, local or cluster mode. In cluster and pseudo-distributed the directory has to be created in HDFS, while in local mode in the file system. In any case you also need to change hive.metastore.warehouse.dir in hive-site.xml.